# digital chip trigger output high on change input

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, pins

I need digital chip (low power consumption, can't use arduino or simular devices) which will put output pin high for a few ms when there is digital change on input pin (from hight to low or from low to high). Digital chip or circuit has one input and output pin. I don't know name of these device or where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I hate to say it, sounds like a job for a 555.

The RC and XOR gate on the trigger detects the edges on the input signal and triggers the 555 configured as a ~1mS one-shot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7rBkw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust R2 and C3 to get the pulse width you desire.

The following are test waveforms when you feed the circuit with the 100Hz signal, shown at top,  note each edge produces one pulse on the bottom waveform.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I want only one pulse and thats it. No trigger every x seconds on output. Or I did i understand worng

Comment: @LUKE no those are just test waveforms when you feed the circuit with the 100Hz signal at the top. Note, each edge produces one pulse on the bottom waveform.